# How to use a simple maven project as a dependency in GWT maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt

I wont to break my `GWT` project in different layers. so I have a database layer in `maven` to manipulate DML operations. Now I want to use this layer in my `GWT-Maven` project. 
if I install this data layer in my local repository like a simple maven project
and use it as a dependency. 
*is it possible?*

- but as per the convection of gwt, this data layer should be reside in
  server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. We have done in one of the project that I have worked on. As you guys are following layered approach you need to have server layer(middle layer) where you will be having all your rpc service classes to listen async calls from client side. This service layer will go in server side. Then you can call your db api/methods in implementation of this rpc services at server end.

Comment: I have simple maven project which contain all DML activity. now I want to use it in a simple GWT project means How GWT project RPC will call the DML operation which exist in other project.

Comment: my data layer project is not a GWT project. so there is no hierarchy of client--> shared-->server

Comment: You need to install your DML project in your maven repo then you it as dependency in your maven based GWT project. As far as you access methods/apis of you DML project in your server side code of gwt project things will work fine.

Comment: thanks but how gwt treat it that DML reside in server side.

Comment: or we can say its a hierarchy exception using maven

Comment: GWT complier only cares about code in client and shared package(defined in *.gwt.xml under source tag). It ignores everything used and referred in server packages. In fact you can create a separate maven module for your server layer as well by adding appropriate dependencies to your GWT webapp.

Comment: Not really, I wish I could have running poc, but you can reach me out if you face any issue around gwt and maven.

Comment: Ajax please check the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262344/error-duplicate-class-in-maven