# Error: duplicate class in maven?

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I am working on a `maven project`. when I run `Maven-clean` command target folder get empty its fine. but when I am trying to run `Maven-install` command after some modification, its showing me a compile time error.

```
 error: duplicate class: com.d8corporation.mailservice.MailService_Service
```

I searched and got the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882295/maven-compilation-error-duplicate-classes)

in second answer

```
 So removing them from version control again, could solve it?
```

I have not so much experience in maven so could some one please explain me what I remove for version control?

Comment: Which version of the maven-compiler-plugin are you using? Are you using annotation processors? Only <=3.1 and >=3.5.1 really work for incremental builds.

Answer (score -1):

I resolve the same issue

> cleaning maven project :-mvn clean
>
> delete com folder from src then compile
>
> copy com from generated to src->main-->java
>
> again compile

Hope this Help..